# Modify csv data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

i have a csv file and want to select one specific colum (date string). then i want to change the format of the date string from `yyyymmdd` to `dd.mm.yyyy` for every entry.

i read the csv file in a dataframe with pandas and then saved the specific column with the header `DATE` to a variable.

```
import pandas as pd

# read csv file
df = pd.read_csv('csv_file')

# save specific column
df_date_col = df['DATE']
```

now i want to change the values in `df_date_col`. How can i do this?
I know i can do it a step before like this:
`df['DATE'] = modify(df['DATE'])`

Is this possible just using the variable `df_date_col`?

If i try `df_date_Col['DATE']=...` it will give a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

> Is this possible just using the variable df_date_col?

Sure, but working with `Series`, so cannot again select by `[]`:

```
df_date_col = df['DATE']
df_date_col = pd.to_datetime(df_date_col, format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```